# In django restframework object level permissions, must the owner of a model be the "User" model or can it be any other model?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm working on a project with django restframework. My question is: must the owner of a model be the "User" model or can it be any other model?

In my case, a user has different stores and each store sells different products. I want each store to be the owner of their product NOT the User.

My permissions.py file is:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

In the code above, how do I set `request.user` to something else? From my understanding, using `==` is comparing the properties rather than setting `obj.owner` to `request.user`

PS. in my model, I've set the field I want to be the owner:

```
class StoreItem(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Store, to_field='id', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

in my serializer, I've also set the owner:

```
class StoreItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='store.owner')

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = [
            ...,
            'owner',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what does `obj` represent in `IsOwnerOrReadOnly`, the store item? If this is the case it doesn't make sense to compare it against a user. Why don't you first rename the field `owner` on your model `StoreItem` to store, since this is what it represents, the `Store`.

Then I would check if the current `store item` belongs to the store.

```py
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner.
        return obj.store.id == get_object_or_404(Store, id=obj.store.id).id
```